# Override navbar gradient colors with less variable

Tags: less, twitter-bootstrap-3

Which LESS variables in `variables.less` are responsible for navbar background gradient?

I want to customize gradient colors of my navbar only by using LESS variables. 
I want to avoid using raw CSS to override navbar background.

According to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar there are no gradient related variables and customizing just `@navbar-default-bg` is not enough for gradient (which is defined by 2 or more colors)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional navbar gradient colors are made by applying `darken` and/or `lighten` functions to `@navbar-default-bg`. So if you need the gradient to be something else than just shades of `@navbar-default-bg` there's no way except "overriding raw CSS".

Comment: My experience in using Bootstrap 3.3.6 - Simply remove the theme.  You could then leverage the power of the LESS variables in this specific instance.

Answer (score 1):

Gradients for the navbar and dropdowns are in the `theme.less` file, [as of this writing the navbar specifically on line 107](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/theme.less#L107) inside this mixin:

```css
.navbar-default {
  #gradient > .vertical(@start-color: lighten(@navbar-default-bg, 10%); @end-color: @navbar-default-bg);
  .reset-filter(); // Remove gradient in IE<10 to fix bug where dropdowns don't get triggered
  border-radius: @navbar-border-radius;
  @shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.15), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
  .box-shadow(@shadow);

  .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    #gradient > .vertical(@start-color: darken(@navbar-default-bg, 5%); @end-color: darken(@navbar-default-bg, 2%));
    .box-shadow(inset 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.075));
  }
}
```

Basically, it appears that these are the key variables:

- navbar *normal*: end color of gradient = `@navbar-default-bg`
- navbar *inverse*: end color of gradient = `@navbar-inverse-bg`
- dropdown *normal* link: start color of gradient = `@dropdown-link-hover-bg`
- dropdown *active* link: start color of gradient = `@dropdown-link-active-bg`